# How to change array all values in javascript by button click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have one array as below in JavaScript :

Actual array in JavaScript:
`array('123456' => '1', '456789' => '0', '789123' =>'1', '4456784' => '0', 'so on...' => '0');`

Wanted result array in JavaScript:
`array('123456' => '1', '456789' => '1', '789123' =>'1', '4456784' => '1', 'so on...' => '1');`

Is there any way to change JavaScript array all values as fix like 1 or 0(In wanted result array) without using any loops like(for, .each, etc...).

Please suggest any idea if there is any possibilities in this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're showing a PHP array in a Dictionary form, Javascript doesn't support Dictionary (yet).

Comment: JS supports dictionary as objects...
The solution is a loop... Why don't you want to use a loop to do the loop job ? You could use a function that do a loop :D

Comment: Use objects as dictionaries. Creating this object with Object.create(null) helps. And you need to use a for in loop to process it.

Comment: you can stringify/replace/parse, but a loop is faster

Comment: There are 1092 elements in array, and maybe it can increase more then this, so is not loop takes more time? So i need shorter way then loop to assign same value in all elements of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define your array in javascript:

```
var arrayData = new Array({'key':'123456','value':'1'}, {'key':'456789','value':'0'},{'key':'789123','value':'1'}, {'key':'4456784','value':'0'});
```

and use array like that :

```
 $.each(arrayData, function(index,data){
     alert(arrayData[index].key);
     alert(arrayData[index].value);
 })
```

and set value in array according to your condition.

Comment: Suppose I have javascript array like you gave, `var arrayData = new Array({'key':'123456','value':'1'}, {'key':'456789','value':'0'},{'key':'789123','value':'1'}, {'key':'4456784','value':'0'});`
And now if i wanted replace its value without using $.each, then how can it be?

Comment: apply check on key and change its value accordingly. 
like : arrayData[index].value = 10